# MS Access and broken reference -- missing utility.mda message

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with MS Access 2007 and I'm trying to migrate it to a Windows 10 computer. Up until now I have been working on Windows XP.

I use visual basic string functions (right left instr...) and lots of system calls (date, CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), Application.FileSearch, FoundFileObj...) and when opening my database on a Windows 10 computer, it recognises neither string function names nor  System calls.

When trying to close the database I get messages that utility.mda is missing.
So I figure that some of these functions are in utility.mda which is included in references in my visual basic editor on my XP Computer.

So I thought OK I download utility.mda on the Windows10 computer  from the MS Access installation cd but the windows10 computer says utility.mda is protected and I can't download it.

Can anyone help? Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is exact message - I can't see it actually saying "it's protected". I don't believe that file is needed anymore. Can you check your references and just eliminate that checkbox and try to compile it to see if errors persist?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a reference problem.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/resolve-reference-issues) Microsoft guide.

Another guide: [Link](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-38.html)